# PYODBC Inserting data into datetime column produces incorrectly formatted table

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am currently writing a program that will take data from an excel spreadsheet and insert it into a sql server table that I have created within the program.

I have previously assigned the datetime column to be a nvarchar(250) for the purpose of getting the overall programme to work, however when I go to change it to datetime, the data is inputted into the wrong columns? The rest of the code worked with the nvarchar datatype aswell.

```
import pyodbc

connection_string = r'connection_string'
data = 'file_path'

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cur = conn.cursor()

createtable = """
create table table1(
    ID Int NULL,
    Date datetime(250) NULL,
    City nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Country nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Image nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Length nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Date_Of_capture nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Comments nvarchar(1000) NULL
    )"""

truncatetable = """truncate table table1"""

with open(data) as file:
    file.readline()
    lines = file.readlines()

if cur.tables(table="table1").fetchone():
    cur.execute(truncatetable)
    for line in lines:
        cols = line.split(',')
        cols = line.replace("'", "")
        sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES({}, '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}','{}','{}')".format(cols[0], cols[1],cols[2], cols[3], cols[4], cols[5], cols[6], cols[7])
        cur.execute(sql)
else:
    cur.execute(createtable)
    for line in lines:
        cols = line.split(',')
        sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES({}, '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}','{}','{}')".format(cols[0], cols[1],cols[2], cols[3], cols[4], cols[5], cols[6], cols[7])
        cur.execute(sql)

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

I would expect the date column to show as a datetime data type whilst being contained within one column however it changes the tables so that all the columns are incorrect and each digit of the date is within a different column?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please add some data, from both the input and the output.

Comment: I have to assume that your `create table` statement is not being executed because `datetime(250)` would definitely throw an exception. Also, read up on *parameterized queries*, and [edit] your question to show us what `lines` looks like.

Comment: Apologies, I can't figure how to show a sample of the data? Any advice?

Comment: You cannot `open` on an Excel file, a binary format types (.xls, .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb). Likely, your data is txt or csv, neither of which are Excel files.

Comment: @Parfait - except that Windows will associate .csv with Excel if Office is installed, so in that case one could be forgiven for thinking that .csv is an "Excel file". ("Well, I double-click the file and it opens in Excel....")

Comment: @MatthewMeek - `print(lines[:2])` should give you the first two elements in the list. The resulting line might be rather long, but as long as you faithfully copy-and-paste the result into your question then someone can always help you with the formatting after the fact.

Comment: Correct @GordThompson and that is a misunderstanding. Excel is simply an interface. Notepad can open CSVs but they are not Notepad files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following best practices:

- Always specify columns in `INSERT INTO` even `SELECT` clauses, specifically use `INSERT INTO myTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)` which helps in readability and maintainability;
- Use parameterization with prepared statement to avoid quote escaping or type casting among other important items. Additionally Python allows tuples to be passed into *params* argument of `cursor.execute()` without listing each individual column.
- Use the `csv` library of Python to traverse CSV files with lists or dictionary for proper alignment and avoid the memory intensive `.readlines()` call;
- Combine `CREATE TABLE` and `TRUNCATE` in one SQL call to avoid `if` conditionals  with cursor fetch call.

See adjusted code.

```
import csv
...

action_query = """
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'mytable')
      BEGIN
        TRUNCATE TABLE table1
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE table1(
           ID Int NULL,
           Date datetime NULL,
           City nvarchar(250) NULL,
           Country nvarchar(250) NULL,
           Image nvarchar(250) NULL,
           Length nvarchar(250) NULL,
           Date_Of_capture nvarchar(250) NULL,
           Comments nvarchar(1000) NULL
        )
      END
""")

cur.execute(action_query)
conn.commit()

# PREPARED STATEMENT
append_query = """INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Date, City, Country, Image, 
                                       Length, Date_Of_capture, Comments)
                  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
               """

# ITERATE THROUGH CSV AND INSERT ROWS
with open(mydatafile) as f:
    next(f) # SKIP HEADERS
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for r in reader:
        # RUN APPEND AND BIND PARAMS
        cur.execute(append_query, params=r)
        conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Unfortunately I am required to check if the table exists in python as I am on a learning course however I was able to take bits of this to complete it! Thank you for your response!

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Hopefully your learning course emphasizes parameterization.